# How to order the result of a SQL query (using INTERSECT)?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `users` and `Q`.
I would like to select some specific `users` (having
user_level= N ) that also have Q_test = -1 AND Q_dummy !='' in a second table `Q`.

The following works nicely (albeit not optimal I guess).

```
SELECT *  from `users` WHERE `user_id` In (SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_level`= 'N' INTERSECT SELECT `Q_id` FROM `Q` WHERE `Q_test` = '-1' AND `Q_dummy` !='');
```

I am now wondering how to order the result by Q_submission_date.
I tried to use the As operator without any success ....

TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `user_level` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `Q` (
  `Q_id` int NOT NULL,
  `Q_test` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL 
  `Q_dummy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And basically Q_id is identical to user_id as :

```
ALTER TABLE `Q`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `MY_C` FOREIGN KEY (`Q_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data ?
OR
Let us know which other columns these tables have

Comment: I have written http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bd8f5/5

Here.
Can you please check whether it works in your code

Comment: Based on your updated alter;
You have to just write :

`ORDER BY (
    SELECT q_dummy FROM q
    WHERE q.q_id = users.user_id
)`

After your current query

Comment: Please carefully replace with your actual column names; As when I started writing query for this; the column names were different.

Also,
As INTERSECT is not supported in MYSQL 5.6; I am not able to save it to SQLFiddle, Please check adding the above lines to your code

Comment: Using your sqlfiddle (BTW, many thanks), I do not need INTERSECT. See for instance :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bd8f5/19. Still I do not see how to order by q6_id. – 
2WFR
 16 mins ago

Comment: Use it like this :

`SELECT *  from users WHERE user_id In 
(SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_level= 'N' 
INTERSECT 
SELECT q_id FROM q WHERE q_test = '-1' AND q_dummy !='')
order by (
    SELECT q_dummy FROM q 
    WHERE q_id = users.user_id
)`

Comment: As per edit; `q6_id` is  `q_id`;
So,
Please carefully replace names with your original columns and tables names

Comment: Hope the order by works now.
Do you still face issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
ORDER BY (SELECT q_dummy FROM q   
WHERE q.q_id = users.user_id);
```

To your existing query.